Sync deleted records option in salesforce not working in Matillion
I am using salesforce increment query to load data into snowflake using matillion.

But when I do a select dictinct isdeleted from from table.
I always get False
How to get deleted records from salesforce into snowflake

When you configure your Salesforce Incremental Load job, make sure you have the Sync Deleted Records option checked on the Salesforce connection:
https://docs.matillion.com/metl/docs/2954752/#salesforce-incremental-load-setup-snowflake

as you can see, It is set to true in the screenshot
